# Diagnostic settings (preview) not working for Azure File

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-monitoring, azure-diagnostics

I created a `Diagnostic settings (preview)` for Azure file and then set the destination as `Stream to an event hub`.

[image]

However, when I tried to preview the events (using `Process Data`) on the eventhub for Azure file, I got nothing returned and got message "There is no data from input `test-logs`".

Here is the eventhub test query from `Process Data`:

[image]

Comment: Same. Absolutely nada. How did you resolve this?